# Error with Multi Dropdown List in Python Dash

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly-dash, dropdownbox

I'm trying to visualize the price development of different financial indices (A, B, C) in an interactive line chart embedded in Python Dash. I want to allow users to select multiple indices and compare them accordingly in the same plot over a specific period of time. At the same time, the plot should also change accordingly when unselecting indices. So far, I was able to plot only one index. The issue I'm having now is that the the plot does not change at all when adding additional indices. I've tried to solve this issue myself for the last couple of hours, but without success, unfortunately.

I'm using Jupyter Notebook. Here's my code with a data sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.express as px

data = [['2020-01-31', 100, 100, 100], ['2020-02-28', 101, 107, 99], ['2020-03-31', 104, 109, 193], ['2020-04-30', 112, 115, 94], ['2020-05-31', 112, 120, 189]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['DATE', 'A', 'B', 'C'])
df = df.set_index('DATE')
df

# create the Dash app
app = dash.Dash()

# set up app layout
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Index Dashboard'),
    dcc.Dropdown(id='index-dropdown',
                options=[{'label': x, 'value': x}
                        for x in df.columns],
                 value='A',
                 multi=True, clearable=True),
    dcc.Graph(id='price-graph')
])

# set up the callback function
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='price-graph', component_property='figure'),
    [Input(component_id='index-dropdown', component_property='value')]
)

def display_time_series(selected_index):
    filtered_index = [df.columns == selected_index]
    fig = px.line(df, x=df.index, y=selected_index,
                 labels={'x', 'x axis label'})
    
    fig.update_layout(
        title="Price Index Development",
        xaxis_title="Month",
        yaxis_title="Price",
        font=dict(size=13))
    
    return fig

# Run local server
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

As I'm relatively new to Python Dash, any help or advice would be extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not applying your filter inside your callback to your data and the filter itself doesn't work.

Instead you can do something like this:

```
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id="price-graph", component_property="figure"),
    [Input(component_id="index-dropdown", component_property="value")],
)
def display_time_series(selected_index):
    dff = df[selected_index] # Only use columns selected in dropdown
    fig = px.line(dff, x=df.index, y=selected_index, labels={"x", "x axis label"})

    fig.update_layout(
        title="Price Index Development",
        xaxis_title="Month",
        yaxis_title="Price",
        font=dict(size=13),
    )

    return fig
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply Bas! I implemented your suggestion into my code. Unfortunately, I'm still facing the same issue as before: selecting multiple values (indices) from the dropbox does not add additional lines/traces to the line chart.

Comment: Works on my end. Are you running the code as you've posted it, but with the callback replaced by the one posted in my answer?

Comment: Yes, I am. I've replaced the callback part accordingly, as you suggested. That's really strange. Maybe it's an issue related to the version of Python that it does not work properly on my end?

Comment: Can you list the python version (`python --version`) and the packages in the active environment, the environment you're running the notebook with (`pip freeze`)?

Comment: **Information obtained via session_info**
-----
dash                        0.39.0
dash_core_components        0.44.0
dash_html_components        0.14.0
pandas                      0.23.0
plotly                      4.5.0
session_info                1.0.0
-----
Click to view modules imported as dependencies
-----
IPython             7.16.1
jupyter_client      6.1.12
jupyter_core        4.7.1
jupyterlab          3.0.14
notebook            6.4.0
-----
**Python 3.6.5** |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
-----

Comment: A lot of those dependencies are fairly old. I'm not able to install these older versions, but I would upgrade the `dash` related dependencies (`dash`, `dash_core_components`, `dash_html_components`) and `pandas`. Or just upgrade everything if you can.

Comment: YEEES!! Now, it works flawlessly after I updated everything. Thank you so much Bas, have a nice day ahead!